# Why can't delete four white blanks at the beginning from 7 to 10 line?

Tags: vim

```
:7,10s/^.\{4}//g
```

I want to remove  four  white blanks  at the beginning from 7 to 10 line,why i get the strange result?
In my vimrc, set softtabstop=4 .
[image]

[image]

4 whith blanks was removed only on line7.
From 8 to 10 line ,more than 4 white blanks were removed,why?

Comment: `.` is "any character excluding EOL". Use `\s` if you want to match "any whitespace character". Also, are you sure you don't have tabs in there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems there are mixed tabs and whitespaces in your file. If you only want to replace whitespace, say so.

```
:7,10s/^ \{4}//g
```

Comment: In my vimrc, set softtabstop=4 .,maybe tabs and whiteblanks mixed by the configuration file vimrc.

Comment: :7,10s/^ \{4}//g  get strange result too.

Comment: 4 whith blanks was removed only on line7.

Comment: From 8 to 10 line  nothing happens.

Comment: Yes, becaue lines 8-10 use tabs instead of whitespaces. You need `expandtab` set to convert tabs to spaces while inserting. Just convert your tabs first `%s/^\t\+/ /g` for example.

Answer (score 1):

you can make use of `<` command.

Depends on your `shiftwidth` setting, you may try:

```
:7,10 <
```

Comment: I was reading `:help :<` and I realized `:7,10<`  and `:7< 4` are equivalent. However, `:7,10< 4` is actually equivalent to `:10 < 4`, i.e., shift 4 lines one `shiftwidth` left, starting with line 10.

Comment: @JairLopez yes, you are right, I made a mistake in the answer.  I correct it now.

Answer (score 0):

The command `:7,10s/^.\{4}//g` removes the first four characters on each line, which in your case may be tabstop characters *or* space characters.

More specifically:

- In line 7, the leading white space consists of 20 space characters (`' '`) of which 4 are removed, which results in `border:...` moving 4 columns to the left.
- In lines 8-10, the leading white space consists of 2 tab stop characters (`\t`) and 4 space characters. This is because a tab stop character is still up to 8 columns wide (read [this techblog](http://tedlogan.com/techblog3.html) for more information about tabs in vim). Now if you remove the first 4 characters, you only have 2 space characters left.

However, to achieve the desired indentation, you can use the indentation commands `<<` and `>>` (taken from [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/16940)):

In *normal mode*, place the cursor on the first line you want to indent, then press `4<<` where `4` is the number of lines that are affected and `<<` is the command to move one indentation level to the left.